# Menu bar for NSDocument doesn't appear

Tags: swift, macos

I transplanted a storyboard to another project that uses xibs (yes, the deployment target for the app is 10.9). This storyboard is connected to a NSDocument subclass (available only on 10.10+) which seems to work very good as expected... but the only problem is the main menu that only appear when the window's document goes behind other windows (such Finder ones) and then I put it back in front.
My question is: how can I ensure the main menu get connected to my document?

```
  override func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
    Swift.print("validateMenuItem")
    return super.validateMenuItem(menuItem)
  }

  override func makeWindowControllers() {
    let wc = DocumentWC.loadFromNib()

    self.addWindowController(wc!)
  }
```

Comment: Is "main menu" the menu bar? Is "window's document" the window of a document? How would a menu bar be connected to a document? Please post a [mre].

Comment: Hi Willeke, yes for both the menu and the window. Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce the problem as every things I do from scratch works as it should.... and I cannot post the project as it's covered by an NDA. I've added two methods I ovveriding to load my document. validateMenuItem is called only after the window of the document goes in the background and then I put back to front. Since this is a borg project probably I made some errors. Consider the menu bar shown is the one in MainMenu.xib while I'm using DocumentWC.storyboard to load my UI document.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causing the problem (the project it's huge), and probably you can call this a patch instead of a fix:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
  super.viewDidAppear()
  if !self.menufixed {
    self.menufixed = true // just to call it once 
    let win = self.view.window
    win?.resignMain()
    win?.becomeMain()
    win?.orderFrontRegardless()
    win?.resignKey()
    win?.becomeKey()
    win?.orderFrontRegardless()
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
  }
}
```

P.S. added to the view controller when the view and the window appear.